# How to identify if Android App is under automated ui tests?

Tags: java, android, ui-testing

I'm trying to identify different test types running on my app, but i don't know how to identify ui tests, like Calabash, Appium and others. I have tried to get events when button clicked but nothing appears to show that is automated.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of UI-test is not to have any special handling, having the the app behave as if it were used by an actual user.

If you're going to build in additional logic in the app's code that will only work (or skip certain behaviour), you may hide bugs that would be discovered by *normal usage*.

When testing for acceptance it's best to have an environment as close to the production as possible, so using actual services and external calls.

What might be a good idea is to have your have a way to have the underlying services (database, storage, external service calls) being replaced with mocks/stubs, without having the UI aware of this. This may make reproducibility easier for scenario's that otherwise require a lot of manual setup to get the initial data right.